# Get parent window from popup element

Tags: wpf, popup

I have popup on my current application. There is one image inside popup control. Now when I click on that image, I want to have object of main app window.

When I write this, it gives me null.

```
Window window = VisualTreeHelpers.FindVisualParent<Window>(Image);
```

And When i write this, it gives me object of POPUP windo, not application window.

```
window =  Window.GetWindow(Image);
```

How would I get main application window from Popup Image control ?

Answer (score 3):

`Application.Current.MainWindow`

> MainWindow is automatically set with a reference to the first Window
>   object to be instantiated in the AppDomain.
>
> You can specify a different main window by setting MainWindow
>   assigning another Windows object to the MainWindow property.

Link to MSDN page is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow.aspx).

Comment: Consider adding some documentation or explanation to this answer :)